# Could I use LLVM for parsing Fortran?

Tags: parsing, fortran, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I am a newbie to LLVM. My basic need is to parse the Fortran codes. By looking at LLVM website, it seems that LLVM can be used as a library for parsing codes. So could I use it to parse Fortran codes, and extract information about the codes (AST?)?

Comment: LLVM has *nothing* to do with parsing. You can reuse a parser from f2c or one of those antlr Fortran grammars. Or simply write your own parser, Fortran is pretty trivial.

Comment: @SK-logic I have started written a Fortran parser using Treetop for my purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LLVM is a compiler backend. The only thing it knows how to parse is LLVM IR - an intermediate language designed to be emitted from programing language frontends. The official frontend for LLVM is Clang, which can handle C, C++ and ObjC. If you're interested in other languages, there's also [DragonEgg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/), which is a LLVM plugin for gcc. It uses gcc's front-end and LLVM as a backend, so it can parse anything gcc knows how to parse. I know that work is being done on making it generate correct code from Ada and Fortran. Here's an excerpt from its page:

> Current Status
>
> - Works best with gcc-4.6.
> - Fortran works very well. Ada, C and C++ also work well. Ada works poorly with gcc-4.7.
> - It can compile a reasonable amount of Obj-C, Obj-C++ and Go.
> - It can compile simple Java programs, but they don't execute properly (this is a consequence of the java front-end not supporting GCC's
>     LTO).
> - Debug info is poor.

Comment: Thanks! So could I use DragonEgg as a library? Like let it parse a Fortran code, and ask it for symbol information.

Comment: @LiDong: If you only need to parse Fortran and get symbol information perhaps you don't even need DragonEgg or LLVM. Perhaps you just need gcc to dump its front-end data. I would look around for documentation on doing that with gcc.

Answer (score 3):

No, LLVM is not a library for parsing Fortran. LLVM is a library for implementing the backend of a compiler. You would need to write the Fortran frontend yourself.

Comment: Or use the work of someone else who has written a Fortran front-end, such as http://dragonegg.llvm.org

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Eli Bendersky comment, you can use -fdump-parse-tree option in gfortran for "output the internal parse tree before starting the code generation".